# How to set up redis for an API using Ruby and Rack?

Tags: ruby, redis, rack, ruby-grape

I'm building a simple API using [Grape](https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape), Ruby, and Rack (no framework).  I want to use redis to store the data the API is working with. So far, I've defined a `Directory` class and a `DirectoryAPI` class using Grape.  The `Directory` class has methods that return JSON data in the exact same way as the API.

I've never had to set up redis before, so I'm not sure how to do it.  What I'm looking to accomplish is:

- Do a mass insert to redis when I run `rackup`, so that there is pre-populated data.  The pre-populated data would come from using my `Directory` class.
- Have my GET routes return a hash stored in redis
- Have the POST route for my API add an entry to redis

How do I configure redis to run and populate when I run `rackup`? Should I do it in my `config.ru` file somehow and define a new class for redis? How would I get the API class to interact with redis?

Answer (score 1):

When I use redis, I do the fallowing:

In my initializers folder I create a file redis.rb and create the connection:

```
`Redis.new(:host => "10.0.1.1", :port => 6380, :db => 15)`
```

Then I assign this conn to a global variable `$redis` so I can have access to it everywhere.

Then it's up to you, you can organise your code however you want.

An example:

```
Controller A
def index
  MemoryModel.getAll()
end

class MemoryModel

  def getAll()
    $redis.get("key")
  end
end
```

Have a look at `redis gem` you can find some examples in there, also connection_pool gem